# Segmentation Fault - Recursividad

Tags: c++, recursión

He creado la siguiente funcion:

```
void imprimir(void){
    cout << "Y\n";
    imprimir();
}
```

Intentando aprender mas sobre la utilidad que podria tener el uso de una funcion recursiva (funcion que se llama a si misma).

Al incluirla en mi codigo, este ha quedado asi:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void imprimir(void){
    cout << "Y\n";
    imprimir();
}

int main(void){

   imprimir();

   return 0;
}
```

Tan simple como que la funcion se ejecute y se siga ejecutando, me he encontrado con el siguiente problema.

Despues de unos segundos, aparecio este mensaje de error:

> Segmentation fault: 11

Porque ocurre esto? Si la recursividad es un concepto de programacion y C++ soporta la recursividad, porque ha ocurrido este error, si la funcion no usa punteros ni nada fuera de lo comun.

Tarda alrededor de 8 segundos en dejar de funcionar. Es necesario incluir algun tiempo de espera?

Comment: Me parece que no es estas definiendo en que momento se va a romper la recursividad y se queda en un bucle infinito por eso te manda ese error.

Comment: Si, pero, si se pueden crear bucles infinitos `while(true)` y estos se ejecutan sin limite, porque no se podria hacer un "bucle", o bien, una ejecucion ilimitada con recursividad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Una llamada a función **implica** varias cosas: hay que colocar argumentos en la pila, y colocar en la misma pila la dirección de retorno (la dirección desde la que llamamos a la función). Eso, como mínimo.

Si realizas llamadas recursivas *al infinito*, mas pronto o mas tarde, la pila será tan grande que interferirá con el resto del programa, o se pasará del límite de tamaño del memoria **por proceso** que el sistema operativo tenga establecido.

Un `while( )`, por su parte, **no es una llamada a función**; no se colocan argumentos en la pila sin fin; se limita a realizar un ciclo, un salto a cierta dirección fija, sin necesidad de tocar la pila para nada.

En algunos lenguajes (C++ entre ellos, pero depende del compilador) es posible, no obstante, **realizar llamadas recursivas sin fin**. Es lo que se conoce como *Tail Call Optimization*. Es un *truco*, mediante el cual **no se introducen nuevos elementos en la pila**, sino que *se reutiliza* el *contexto* actual.

Si tu compilador lo soporta, puedes hacer

```
void imprimir(void){
  static const char msg = "Y\n";

  cout << msg;
  return imprimir();
}
```

sin llegar nunca a recibir el mensaje (pero disparando el uso de CPU).

Observa los *sutiles* cambios. Usamos un mensaje declarado como `static`, para que no se use la pila, y colocamos un `return` **delante** de la llamada recursiva.

**Nota**

C++ es famoso **por las múltiples llamadas a constructores y destructores** *ocultas* **detras** de operaciones aparentemente inocuas. Una simple asignación puede requerir múltiples llamadas a constructor/destructor, y cada una con su correspondiente uso de la pila. A partir de C++11, esto disminuye bastante (casi se elimina, gracias a los constructores *move* y *idem* operadores de asignación).

Comment: Quiza entendiste un poco mal lo que indicaba yo en los comentarios, no estaba confundiendo la recursividad con los ciclos, me referia que si uno puede usar un bucle para infinitas ejecuciones, porque una funcion recursiva no puede ejecutarse infinitas veces

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, me ha dejado claro el porque de este error.

Comment: @IvanBotero Como siempre, un placer :-) La pila, el marco de pila (*stack frame*), *Tail Call Optimization*, convenciones de llamada (*call convention*), ... son temas interesante. Si te defiendes en inglés, hay mucha info disponible.

Answer (score 2):

```
void imprimir(void){
    cout << "Y\n";
    imprimir();
}
```

Vamos a analizar el comportamiento de la aplicación:

```
imprime "Y"
llama a imprimir()
imprime "Y"
llama a imprimir()
imprime "Y"
llama a imprimir()
imprime "Y"
...
```

Y así hasta el infinito. ¿El problema? Que cada llamada a `imprimir()` consume espacio en la pila del programa ya que el sistema necesita saber a dónde tiene que volver cuando abandone la función a la que se está llamando.

Es fácil entender que en un espacio finito (la pila tiene un tamaño determinado) no entra una cantidad infinita de información (la llamada recursiva se repetirá indefinidamente). Así pues en algún momento la pila del programa se llenará y el Sistema Operativo matará la aplicación para proteger la integridad de la memoria del resto de procesos.

La recursividad necesita **siempre** un tope que limite el máximo de iteraciones so pena de provocar un mal funcionamiento del programa.

Un ejemplo:

```
void imprimir(int valor)
{
  if( valor < 0 ) return; // Para abandonar la recursividad
  std::cout << valor << '\n';
  imprimir(valor-1);
}

int main()
{
  imprimir(10);
}
```