# Duda sobre la sentencia "return" en recursividad - C

Tags: c, funciones, recursión

Estoy estudiando el tema de recursividad y tengo dos dudas que consisten en lo siguiente:

**1.-**
He visto que normalmente al llamar dentro de si misma a una funcion se hace por medio de **return**, algo como lo siguiente:

```
return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
```

Mi duda es si aún se considera recursividad si se llama a si misma **sin** un **return**, por ejemplo:

```
void funcionRecursiva (/*Parámetros*/)
{
    //Caso base
    if (/*Alguna condicional aquí*/) return;

    /*
     *
     * Codigo
     *
    */

    funcionRecursiva (/*Parámetros*/);
}
```

La función de arriba se llamaría a si misma hasta que se llegara a cumplir una cierta condición (caso base), y si no se cumple, se llama a si misma hasta que se cumpla, pero no se llama a si misma con un **return**, ¿Eso hace que ya no "cuente" como recursividad?

**2.-**
Si lo anterior no "cuenta" como recursividad, ¿Contaría si se cambia a algo como esto?:

```
void funcionRecursiva (/*Parámetros*/)
{
    //Caso base
    if (/*Alguna condicional aquí*/) return;

    /*
     *
     * Codigo
     *
    */

    return funcionRecursiva (/*Parámetros*/);
}
```

¿Es correcto llamar a una funcion dentro de si misma usando un return si dicha funcion es de tipo **void**?

Agradezco toda la ayuda y dirección que pudieran darme. Gracias.

Comment: estás seguro que `return funcionRecursiva (/*Parámetros*/);` con void es válido? compila?

Comment: @Arie CwHat Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tu ayuda. Si compila, lo he probado y en los casos que lo he usado si se comporta correctamente. Sin embargo, usando -pedantic marca una advertencia, mas no se que consecuencias pudiera tener el ignorarla. La advertencia es "[Warning] ISO C forbids 'return' with expression, in function returning void [-Wpedantic]".

Comment: Hmm, es que si el tipo retorno es void, no tiene mucho sentido devolver una función que retorne void, es lo mismo llamar a la función y en la linea siguiente solo poner return.. solo que en una linea :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como te han indicado, una función *recursiva* es aquella que se llama a sí misma. No tiene más.

Lo de llamarla en un `return` es para utilizar una **optimización del compilador**, de forma que **se reutilize la pila** para la llamada, con lo que la pila no crecerá innecesariamente si ya no la necesitamos mas.

Dicha optimización solo se puede utilizar cuando **no necesitemos realizar ningún cálculo entre el valor devuelto por la llamada recursiva y alguna variable interna de la función**.

Puedes mirar [Segmentation Fault - Recursividad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/58366/19610) para mas detalles.

Comment: Comprendo, pero `return imprimir();` no agrega elementos a la pila... entonces es una optimizacion del compilador? que sucede si solo llamas a la funcion sin return en la ultima linea de la función? se comporta igual? :P

Comment: @ArieCwHat Se comporta igual, pero **no optimiza**; no **reutiliza la pila**; sin el `return`, crea un marco de pila nuevo,  realiza la llamada, destruye el marco de pila que se creó, y continua. Con el `return`, **no crea un marco de pila nuevo**, sino que **reutliza el marco de pila actual**.

Comment: :O , por eso siempre desconfié de c y c++, son muy mañosos :(

Comment: Muy útil la información, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5):

El primer caso **sí** es una llamada recursiva, esta cumple la condición de invocarse a sí misma dentro de su definición.  El hecho que devuelva un valor o no a través de `return` no está relacionado a la recursión.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, as resuelto mi duda.